# How To Filter JSON data parser

Tags: json, swift, swift3, filter, alamofire

**JSON** response
tranArr

```
[{

"total_amt" : -10000,
"tran_type" : "C3",
"pay_type" : "05",
"tran_time" : "20180125 133122",
"point_total" : 0
 },

 {

"total_amt" : -1004,
"tran_type" : "C5",
"pay_type" : "05",
"tran_time" : "20180124 163602",
"point_total" : 0
}]
```

=====================

I want to filter tran_type = "C3"

What should I do?

```
"total_amt" : -10000,
"tran_type" : "C3",
"pay_type" : "05",
"tran_time" : "20180125 133122",
"point_total" : 0
```

Comment: "What should I do?"  Locate a search box at the top and have it your way.

Comment: `json.filter { return $0["tran_type"] as? String == "C3" }` Anyway such thing is not a valid data structure, you should replace `{` with `[` and `}` with `]`

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let string = "[{ \"total_amt\" : -10000,\"tran_type\" : \"C3\", \"pay_type\" : \"05\", \"tran_time\" : \"20180125 133122\", \"point_total\" : 0},{\"total_amt\" : -1004,\"tran_type\" : \"C5\", \"pay_type\" : \"05\", \"tran_time\" : \"20180124 163602\", \"point_total\" : 0 }]"

// Convert string to Data
let jsonData = string.data(using: .utf8)!

do {
    // Serialize the json Data and cast it into Array of Dictionary
    let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: .allowFragments) as? [[String: Any]]

    // Apply filter on `tran_type`
    let tranArr = jsonObject?.filter({ (dictionary) -> Bool in
        dictionary["tran_type"] as? String == "C3"
    })

    print(tranArr)

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Filtered result will be in `tranArr` object.